# BeautifulSoup - Is there a way to find starting from a specific row number?

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using python and BeautifulSoup for making a discord bot
I have my code:

```
URL = "https://www.mywebsite.com"

   with requests.Session() as s:
     r = s.post(URL)
     soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html5lib')
     firstresult = soup.find_all('p',attrs={"class" : "myclass"}, limit=6)
     secondresult = soup.find_all('p',attrs={"class" : "myclass"})
```

'firstresult' finds the first 6 tags in the page.
I want the 'secondresult' to find all the tags starting from 6 because i already have the first 6 in 'firstresult'

Comment: Why use limit for first result? Grab the list once and slice rather than parse the DOM twice.

Answer (score 1):

To access all tags from the *6th tag* onward, since `find_all()` returns a `list`, you can use index slicing (zero index based):

```
secondresult = soup.find_all('p',attrs={"class" : "myclass"})[5:]
```